# Can you integrate an electromagnetic coil (torque rod) to a PCB design in EAGLE?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, eaglecad, coil, electromagnetic

I am new in using EAGLE and I am currently trying to design a magnetorquer board. I would like to ask if it is possible to somehow create a solid-core  electromagnetic coil (torque rod) that has known electrical and physical values: core (material, size-diameter and length-)and wire characteristics (number of windings, size, max current carrying capabilities, etc) in such a way to integrate it into my PCB design.

Moreover, i would like to create an air coil electromagnetic core in a rounded square for the back side of the same PCB.

For better undestanding, I will link the [ISIS Magnetorquer board](https://www.isispace.nl/product/isis-magnetorquer-board/) with images of its [top](https://www.isispace.nl/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/ISIS-imtq-magnetorquer-board-.png) and [bottom](https://www.isispace.nl/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/imtq-back-min.jpg) views. Therefore, succinctly,my question is I can somehow integrate the electromagnetic coils to the PCB design or in the worse case scenario if there exists a library that include any customizable electromagnetic coils or any pre-made ones.

If not, is there any other program that can do this and that can be accessible to a newbie? (I'm running very low on time so I would take just about anything now)

EDIT:As the question is a little bit abstract(i am truly sorry for that), I will try to make it more specific with the help of your feedback.

EDIT4: In the links above, the electromagnetic coils (torque rods) are mounted on the PCB by using a plastic (or another material) support as seen in the links above, so they are separate components. **The question above should have been how do I take these coils into consideration when designing the PCB in EAGLE.**
I believed that there is an electromagnetic coils library or that I can design it myself as a part somehow and this is the reasoning for the weirdly phrased question.

EDIT2:

Comment: Those appear to just be coil components soldered to a PCB, rather than anything special with the PCB itself.

Comment: Indeed they are soldered, but shouldn't they be somehow taken into consideration when designing the PCB? If so, how does one do that with EAGLE? Is there any other element I can replace them with?

Yes, the question is weirdly formulated, i will try to edit it and fix it with the feedback i get.

Comment: _"... that I can design it myself as a part somehow"_ - if the coils are a component soldered onto the board then that is what you must do.

Comment: @BruceAbbott The design of a coil is not a hard job, as I have said, i have all the calculation and elements needed, but how can I make a connection between it and the PCB design in EAGLE? How should I take into consideration the coil in the PCB design if I cannot add it as a "part" in neither the schematic or the board. Or can I? How?

Comment: If it's soldered onto the board, why would you not be able to create a part for it in Eagle?

Comment: I will start by apologizing for my inability of understanding certain terms.
And continue by correcting my previous statement by mentioning that the coil is just mounted on the PCB by a plastic support as shown in the links in the question. Therefore, it is not soldered...
The coil in question is a  [magnetorquer rod](https://www.cubesatshop.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/NSS-Magnetorquer-Rod-min.png) mounted on the PCB. My question would be how can I take this into consideration when I am designing the PCB in EAGLE, as the design should adapt to the characteristics of the coil

Comment: The answer below shows how to do this with no part, with the traces built into the board and describes how I built one with wire. In many cases cubesats have both, but the size of the coil will depend on the ADCS requirements.

Answer (score 4):

You can integrate coils into the PCB, yes. Is it efficient? No.

> Q-factor of PCB inductors is generally lowered then Q-factor of the
> inductors having a coil of wire and less than that of the cylindrical
> microstrip coils. The self-capacitance of the printed inductors
> depends on the width of the spiral turns, the gap between them and the
> PCB material and can reach 3 to 5 pF, which is pretty high at such
> frequencies

Source: https://coil32.net/pcb-coil.html

The magnetic moment is a factor of the number of turns, the current and the area. So many torquer coils are simply rectangles built into one or more layers of the PCB.

m = n*A*I

More turns are easier to create with wire, which has a much higher packing factor for current carrying wires than a PCB (or flat flex), because enamel is much smaller than layers of a PCB or flat flex. It really depends on the magnetic moment needed, if you need a high magnetic moment, then you might have to resort to wire outside of the PCB, because most PCB's are fabricated with 4 layers (you can do more, but it comes with a cost).

If you do wish to create a magnetorquer on a PCB, eagle (or any PCB software), just draw the pattern out by hand in the software.

In the design I used for a magnetorquer (which flew) I personally wound a rectangular delrin frame with about 400 turns, which was then fastened to 4 posts on the PCB. The wire was soldered into vias. I remember that the other 2 torquer coils were built into the solar panel arrays.

Here is a paper describing a satellite with coils built in to the PCB with copper traces forming the coil:
[image]

Source: [Innovative power management ADCS](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/259509038_Innovative_power_management_attitude_determination_and_control_tile_for_CubeSat_standard_NanoSatellites/figures?lo=1)

Comment: Thank you for the answer and for taking your time to explain this, it is very interesting and I will probably read more into it in the future. It is not what I need, but it is entirely my fault for not being clear.

Comment: Is your question how to create a part in eagle? There are no standardized libraries for torquer coils, they are *all custom designs*

Comment: Yes. It is about how to create i create a [torque rod](https://www.cubesatshop.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/NSS-Magnetorquer-Rod-min.png) part so I can use it in the "schematic" and "board" parts of the project.


Or how to take this torque rod and its electrical characteristics into consideration when designing a PCB in Eagle ( [example of the finished product](https://www.isispace.nl/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/ISIS-imtq-magnetorquer-board-.png) )